# How to change keyboard sleep button to hibernate?

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys, power-management, suspend, hibernate

I have a keyboard with a "sleep" button that does indeed make my computer go to sleep. The problem is that Ubuntu can't really handle sleep on my computer, causing it go into a non-responsive mode, having the CPU fan spinning at full speed and it stops receiving any input.

Hibernation instead works mainly as it should. I would like to set the sleep key to hibernate, but the keyboard settings' hotkeys tab doesn't have this "sleep" keybinding and though I could make new one with `hibernate --force` as the command, it would require root rights to run.

How can I change the keyboard sleep button action to hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have administrator privileges on your machine, you could try prepending `gksudo` to the front of your command, like so:

```
gksudo -S hibernate --force
```

Then when you press the key, you will be presented with a password entry popup, and hibernation should occur if you enter it correctly.

If you want this command to look nicer and be more self-descriptive when run, you can alternatively use the following:

```
gksudo -S -m "Enter your administrator password to hibernate." hibernate --force
```

(You can change the message between the quotation marks with anything you like.)

Comment: But i was wondering also where its defined that this sleep button suspends the computer :S

Comment: @Allu2 I wouldn't know about that, but nonetheless my provided commands could be bound to that key and should provide the same functionality.